# What is the proper way to create an object with a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, belongs-to

I'm pretty new to rails, and I have some trouble getting the philosophy and finding the "proper" way to create an object as a dependency of an other one.

I have a `Backlog` model :

```
class Backlog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_stories
end
```

and a `UserStory` model :

```
class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :backlog
end
```

On the show action of the `Backlog` controller, I want to display a link to create a `UserStory` that belongs to the current `Backlog`. I want it to redirect to the `UserStory` creation form.

```
<%= link_to 'New User story', "???" %>
```

if I put `new_user_story_path`, it creates a new `UserStory` but does not add it to the `Backlog`.

How should I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have nested routes.

`app/config/rotues.rb`

```
CodeGlot::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :backlogs do
    resources :user_stories
  end

end
```

Then you need to have a nested link:

`index.html.erb # or whatever file`

```
<%= link-to "New user story", new_backlog_user_story_path(backlog) %>
```

*make sure you have a varible backlog, otherwise the route will fail.

`app/controllers/user_stories_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :get_backlog

def get_backlog
    if params[:backlog_id]
        @backlog = Backlog.find(params[:backlog_id])
    end
end

def new
end
```

`app/views/user_stories/new.html.erb`

```
<div class="form">
<%= form_for([@backlog, @user_stories]) do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit",  :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

`app/models/backlog.rb`

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_stories
```

Comment: let me know if you get errors and you don't know how to fix them.

Comment: The "accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_stories" is not required, since there is no nested form involved.

Comment: Absolutely Correct. You do not need that. I basically took this code from a project that does so that's why it's there. Thanks `blackbird07`